# Extract audio from video in python

Tags: python, audio, video, audiovideoplayback, pyffmpeg

I am trying to extract the audio file from a video file and save it to a wav file and then again combine the audio and video together in python3. I have found many tutorials using `ffmpeg` but I don't want to use any external tool to do the task. It will be helpful if someone gives me any suggestion on how to do it in python. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

read this site for instructions https://medium.com/@steadylearner/how-to-extract-audio-from-the-video-with-python-aea325f434b6

```py
    import sys
    from moviepy.editor import *
    video = VideoFileClip(sys.argv[1])
    audio = video.audio
    audio.write_audiofile(sys.argv[2])
    //1. Save this file as extract_audio.py
    //2. Type $python extract_audio.py video_for_audio.mp4 audio_from_video.mp4
```

Comment: it says `audio` is `NONE TYPE`

Comment: I got RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install imageio-ffmpeg' instead.'